# Are there any good demonstrations of phosphorylation cascades?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling

So I'm working on this 2D signal transduction pathway computer simulation, and I'm struggling to grasp this process of protein kinases phosphorylating each other over and over again during the "transduction" part of a signal transduction pathway.

Are there any good sources that demonstrate and explain this process in-depth? I'm looking for videos/charts/textbooks/blog posts etc. anything would work.

Comment: Just use [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com) and search for a review of your signaling pathway of choice. A good one is ERK/MAPK. It's been studied very closely for years and is well-characterized, as well as being involved in a number of key cellular processes.